# Automator workflow or AppleScript to close Safari after a period of time

Tags: applescript, automator

I would like to create an Automator workflow (or some similar function) that will close down Safari after a specified period of time.

For instance, I simply want to run Pandora in Safari during the night, but have it close out after 30 minutes to 1 hour, as sort of a sleep timer. I am a very new Mac user so detailed instructions would be great. I have familiarized myself with creating some simple Automator workflows, but I have no experience using AppleScript.

Comment: Assuming you have regular sleeping hour (say 12am everyday), would it be better for you to schedule a sleep at 12:30am, to put the whole computer to sleep instead of just closing Safari?

Comment: To schedule, go to System Preference -> Energy Saver -> Schedule.

Comment: I'd thought of this, but for other reasons I typically only run my TimeMachine backup among other things during the night; would prefer not to put the machine to sleep

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the AppleScript code, which you can put in your workflow, by implementing an AppleScript item, and copy-paste the code in.  The time is configurable, but you need an exact sleep time, which I can add if you could elaborate some more on the time.  Here is the code via [CulturedCode](https://culturedcode.com/forums/read.php?7,30174,30596).

```
global quit_after, check_every

set quit_after to 2700
set check_every to 10
set minute to quit_after / 60

display dialog "Check is performed every " & check_every & " seconds. Things will be quit after " & minute & " minutesof system inactivity."

on reopen
    display dialog "Check is performed every " & check_every & " seconds. Things will be quit after " & minute & " minutes of system inactivity."
end reopen

on idle
    set idletime to do shell script "echo $((`ioreg -c IOHIDSystem | sed -e '/HIDIdleTime/ !{ d' -e 't' -e '}' -e 's/.* = //g' -e 'q'` / 1000000000))"
    if (idletime as integer) > quit_after then
        tell application "System Events"
            if ((name of processes) contains "Safari") then
                tell application "Safari" to quit
            end if
        end tell
    end if
    return check_every
end idle
```

Comment: This looks great so far - if you could edit it to quit after, say, 45 minutes I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: How might I adapt this such that an Xserve system will only close the Safari instances associated with inactive user sessions, on a multi-user-session system?